# scala self generic illegal inheritance

Tags: scala, oop, generics, inheritance

Basicaly this is what I am trying to do.
A trait that has a member and another trait that inherits that member and initialize it.
Then a class that takes a generic type that must be inherited from the first trait and accesses that member

```
object main extends App{
val z =  new c[b]()
  z.p()
}

trait a{
  val x : String
}

trait b extends a {
  val x = 1
}

class c [A <: a]  {
  self: A =>
  def p(): Unit ={
    print(x)
  }
}
```

but in the line

```
val z =  new c[b]()
```

c[b] is underlined and the compiler complains that

> "Illegal inheritance, self-type c[b] does not conform to A"

I want to define multiple traits that inherit from a father trait and then define a class that takes one of the fathers child traits and accesses its values

Comment: In such cases it helps alot to stick to naming conventions: a) classes, traits start with uppercase. b) Type parameters: single upper case letter c) Other classes not single letter.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, I simply had to extend the object while creating it, like this:

```
object main extends App{
val z =  new c[b] with b
  z.p()
}

trait a{
  val x : String
}

trait b extends a {
  val x = "1"
}

class c[A <: a]{
  this: A =>
  def p(): Unit ={
    print(x)
  }
}
```